# Refresh html for directive accord model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need generate ratings. Rating it is integer value beetwen 0 - 15.
Rating have levels. (5 stars: bronze, silver, gold)

So i need such html

```
<span class="tb-ratings CLASS" ng-bind-html-unsafe="stars">
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    <i></i>
    ...
</span>
```

I had add directive

Now i have problems:

- "i" tags count is not refreshing on rating changes via input (no add, no remove) - see example on http://jsfiddle.net/AdKd8/1/
- need raw html, no unsafe (ng-bind-html-unsafe not works in example)

App code:
http://jsfiddle.net/AdKd8/1/

HTML:
    
        
           rating:

```
<br>need simular result:
e.g 1
<span class="tb-ratings cap" ng-bind-html-unsafe="stars">
    <i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
i{
    background-color: #f093f0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
    display:block;
}

.cap i{
    background-color: red;
}

.crown i{
    background-color: green;
}

.blue i{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

JS:
    function RateCtrl($scope) {
      $scope.rating = 14;
    }

```
angular.module('myapp', []).
  directive('myrating', function() {
        var directive = { restrict: 'E', replace: true, scope: { rating: '=' } };
      directive.template = "<h1><span class='tb-ratings {{class_value}}' ng-bind-html-unsafe='stars'></span>{{stars}}</h1>";

        directive.link = function(scope, element, attributes) {
           function gen_html(rating_value){
                if(!rating_value){
                  return
                }

                scope.class_value = "";
                var stars_count = 0;
                var step = 5
                var class_arr = ["blue", "cap", "crown"];

                for(var i=0; i<3; i++){
                    if(rating_value > step){
                        scope.class_value = class_arr[i];
                        stars_count = rating_value - step;
                    }
                    step+=5;
                }

                scope.stars = "";
                for(var i=0;i<stars_count;i++){
                    scope.stars+="<i></i>";
                }
            }
            gen_html(scope.rating);
        }

        return directive;
  })
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/AdKd8/1/

Comment: some modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/AdKd8/2/

Comment: `ng-bind-html-unsafe` was used in Angular 1.1, deprecated since version 1.2. Use [ng-bind-html](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.19/docs/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you should do to make it work:

- Include angular-sanitize in your project
- Declare ngSanitize in your module
- Use ng-bind-html instead of ng-bind-html-unsafe (deprecated as przno said)
- Remove {{stars}} from your template
- Add a watch so the stars get updated when you change  the value in your input

  ```
  scope.$watch('rating', function(newValue, oldValue){
      gen_html(newValue);});            
  }
  ```

Here is a [working example] (http://jsfiddle.net/27sb5/1/)